# Spring security 'Expected CSRF token not found...' after payments callback

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have Tomcat 8, Spring 4.2 and Spring security 4.0 on server. I try implement payments integration. After successful payment process payments service request to my server using GET to `http://www.example.com/p/paysera/callback?data=cHJvamVjdGlkPTIzMTY0Jm9yZGVyaWQ...` and wait "OK" from me but my server return   `Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?`. But if I copy/paste this url directly to browser everything works ok.

Spring security config:

```
    http
    .httpBasic()
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(..,"/p/**",..).permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
    .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
    .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
```

controller:

```
...
@RequestMapping(value = "/p/paysera/callback", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String paysera_callback(@RequestParam("data") String data,@RequestParam("ss1") String ss1){ ...
```

Comment: Did you add the CSRF token in your JSP code.

Comment: my controller return string not use jsp

Comment: A GET should not cause CSRF error. Are you sure payments service does a GET and not a POST?

Comment: But I am not talking about your controller... Didn't you read that?

Comment: #holmis83 yes, payments service does a GET. I tried change controller to  POST ,but got some error. #We are Borg about what you are toking if not about controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/p/paysera/callback")` to Spring security configuration.